# Is this property about a monotonic function between DCPOs true?

Tags: order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let $P$ anq $Q$ be dcpos, $f : P \to Q$ be a monotonic function and $D$ be a directed subset of $P$.

Is it the case that: if $y$ is an upper bound of $f(D)$, then $f(\vee D) \le y$.

Comment: You should precise "non decreasing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: $P=Q=([-1,1],\le)$, $D=[-1,0)$, $f=\mathbf1_{[0,1]}$ ([indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)), $y=0$.